# Using Multiple For-Loops in C

Tags: c, loops

My assignment is a coin-toss simulation that has to run 10, 100, 1000, 100,000 and 1 million trials.  In other words, one execution of the program encompasses all six trials.  The code for the actual coin toss must be done in another function.  I'm wondering whether it's possible to write a program that has multiple non-nested loops, such as:

```
for(unsigned int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)

for(unsigned int counter = 1; counter <= 100; counter++)
```

Etc

EDIT: The output must say something like:

```
Trials: 10   Heads: 30% Tails 70%
Trials: 100 ….
```

And so on.  Forgot to include this, sorry!

Obviously, this is very tedious to write, and I don't want to have to call my coinToss function six times; but I'm not sure how else to simulate the coin-toss under each trial (10... 1 million).

Comment: Sure, you can have as many loops as you want. If you think six calls is too many (it's not), you could next them I suppose. An outer loop that calls the coin tossing loop would be something like this: `for (unsigned int loop = 10; loop <= 1000000; loop*=10)`

Comment: Those are only five trials.

Comment: otoh you can have one loop that goes to 1 million, and in that loop you can have if statements < 10 if < 100 and so on

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline  Your loop is what I originally had.  I will go back to edit my post, but I have to actually print the results of each trial and I thought such a loop wouldn't work.  I forgot to include this part

Comment: @Nikki I don't see the problem. Why can't you just use an outer loop?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Please, consider rewriting your comment as an answer.

Comment: "I'm wondering whether it's possible to write a program that..." The answer to questions that starts this way is almost always "yes". The follow up question in this case should be "is there a better way to do this?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here are a few.

1) Use an outer loop to generate the number of trials. Works well if the number of trials follows an easily generated pattern, which is the case in your question.

```
for (unsigned int trials = 10; trials <= 1000000; trials *= 10)
    for(unsigned int counter = 1; counter <= trials; counter++)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

2) Use a table with arbitrary values if the pattern is not easy to generate.

```
unsigned int trials[] = { 15, 97, 1003, 10100, 100444, 999999, 0 };
for (int i = 0; trials[i] > 0; i++)
    for(unsigned int counter = 1; counter <= trials[i]; counter++)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

3) Put the loop into a function and call the function multiple times.

```
void foo(unsigned int trials)
{
    for(unsigned int counter = 1; counter <= trials; counter++)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    foo(10);
    foo(100);
    foo(1000);
    foo(10000);
    foo(100000);
    foo(1000000);   
}
```

You can also combine 3) with 1) or 2). For example combining 3) with 1) looks like this

```
void foo(unsigned int trials)
{
    for(unsigned int counter = 1; counter <= trials; counter++)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned int trials = 10; trials <= 1000000; trials *= 10)
        foo(trials);
}
```

Comment: And a refinement to suggestion #3 is to put a loop in `main()` which calls `foo()` rather than 6 explicit calls. This can be done with either pattern from #1 or #2.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That's what I meant by *"can be combined with 1 and 2"*, but I admit that was a little vague. I've edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I missed that parenthetical in my first reading. The edit certainly makes it more clear and obvious.

Comment: I tried #3 and it worked beautifully!  I didn't want to call my function six times, but your example was so clean that I figured, "why not?"  Thanks!